# Uncaught TypeError: z.fn.dropdown is undefined

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select

I want to create a simple select option with `bootstrap-select. I'm using bootstrap-select to create my select picker.

I see this error in the console.

[image: error]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <title>مدیریت</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: Tahoma;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lang">زبان</label>
                <select id="lang" name="lang" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">فارسی</option>
                    <option value="2">عربی</option>
                    <option value="3">انگلیسی</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/defaults-fa_IR.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#lang').selectpicker();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use following version of select picker

https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/archive/v1.14.0-beta2.zip

Comment: You saved my life! But... why is that? What makes this version different?

Comment: it means that `bootstrap` <=> `bootstrap-select` aren't "working together" so it's basically either bootstrap/popper version adjustments or bootstrap-select version adjustments ...